# A question on a linear injective operator

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

Let the standard orthonormal basis be given in the $n$-dimensional Euclidean space
$$
e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0),
$$
$$
e_2=(0,1,\ldots,0),
$$
$$
\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots\ldots,
$$
$$
e_n=(0,0,\ldots,1)
$$
and a linear injective operator $A$ maps a sum of $m$ different vectors of this basis
$$
e_{i_1}+e_{i_2}+\ldots+e_{i_m}
$$
to a sum of $m$ different vectors of this basis
$$
e_{j_1}+e_{j_2}+\ldots+e_{j_m}
$$
(here $m$ is fixed, $1<m<n$).

Will the matrix of this linear operator in this basis be a permutation matrix?

As I see, for the case $m=1$ the operator needs to be required injectivity.

Comment: It will be helpful if you can write the formula for the linear map.

Comment: Please show us the own effort to solve the problem. For instance, what happens in the case $n=3$ and $m=2$?